# How is the range defined for this for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
a = int(input()) 
# number of space separated integers needed to be taken as input.

A = [int(i) for i in input().split()] 
# How is the range of 'a' defined here so it takes only that many space separated values.

print(A)
```

Sample Input :

4

1 2 3 4

Output:

[1,2,3,4]

Any help or explanation would be really appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Explanation of **what**?

Comment: A = [int(i) for i in input().split()][:a] - this, I understand how it works. But it still works when in remove "[:a]", this i don't understand why it works.

Comment: `a` is completely useless in your program.  The `.split()` will produce a list of however many space-separated items are actually present; it doesn't do you any good to know how many that will be in advance.  This is from some online programming contest site, I assume?  Those that support multiple languages will typically include an input size parameter like this, for the benefit of programming languages where you can't easily handle variable-length input without knowing the length.

Comment: I was practicing on hackerrank problems, was a bit puzzled when I came across this. The input size parameter included in the site makes sense. Thanks for the explaination @jasonharper

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.